# Change the distance between multiple lines in axis label

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I need to plot two lines for x-axis label. Because I need to use special font I choose to use "expression" with "atop". The problem is that the distance between the two lines is much bigger than that if I just use "\n". Like the following:

```
xlabs <- c('change in log2\nsample A', 
            expression(atop('change in'~log['2'], 'sample B')))
```

I got something like this:

[image]

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the graphical parameter `lheight` together with `mtext` to adjust the line spacing to anything you want

```
plot(1:100, xlab = '')
par(lheight = 1.1)
mtext(xlabs[1], side = 1, line = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the question was how to narrow the spacing for `xlabs[[2]]`????

Comment: @42- Hmm - I assumed that the only reason for using xlabs[2] was because with the special font, xlab[1] would not give the right spacing either. Perhaps OP can clarify if this solution will work for them.

Comment: He was getting the special font by using the font linked to `plotmath` expressions.

Comment: Ok - that makes sense. Its a lot clearer now the question has been edited. I guess I'll leave this answer up anyway as it may be useful to others. Someone googling "how to change distance between label lines" could easily end up here.

Answer (score 0):

I think using an expression vector is what was requested:

```
exl <- list(quote(line~1), quote(line~2))
plot(0:1,0:1,type="n",xlab="")
mtext(side=1, do.call(expression,exl),line=1:2)
```

These also succeeds (and might point the way to a more flexible approach to using an expression vector:

```
plot(0:1,0:1,type="n",xlab="")
mtext(side=1, expression(line*1, line*2), line=1:2)

plot(0:1,0:1,type="n",xlab="")
mtext(side=1, c(bquote(line==.(round(exp(1),2))), expression(line*2)), line=1:2)
```